# Switching HTML menu value before submit?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a menu with a list of every country and its abbreviation.  I want to send the full name (the text of the menu option) instead of the value.  So I tried to make a function, `switchval()`, to do this but it did not switch the values.  Any ideas?

```
function switchval(){
    var countries = document.getElementById('countries');
    countries = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('countries').value = countries;
}
```

Comment: I would just avoid giving options a value attribute.

Comment: Why aren't you just changing the `<select>` to have the values you want?

Comment: Why not just make the values the country names in the first place?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking - do you have a `select` element that is posted via a form, and you want the text of the selected element - `<option value="tx">Texas</option>` - you'd want "Texas" to post instead of "tx" ?

Comment: Are you sure that your function is even being called?  Why not recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @MattH  Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.  And to everyone else, I know it's a stupid way of doing things, it's for a project.

Comment: Please show the "menu" code. If it's a Select tag (which it looks like) you can use the <option value="desiredVariablePassed">Display Value</option> without the use of the javascript

Comment: @James, Yes I know, but the point of the assignment is to switch the value submitted to the text in the option.  I agree it's unneeded and  complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the option element. I changed the variable names so they make more sense. Please consider your coding style and use good variable names, and don't use a variable twice for a different datatype (that is insane). Also, setting the value of the option element is just plain wrong, I felt dirty typing this.

```
function switchval(){

    var selectEl = document.getElementById('countries');
    var optionEl = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex];
    var country = optionEl.text;

    optionEl.value = country;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll second what buddhabrot showed and said - changing the `value` property is wrong and might not be supported in all browsers.

I would use a `hidden` element and set the `text` property into that, changing the name of the `select` element to something like "countries-select" and making the hidden element "countries".

That way when your form posts, it will have the proper "name" for the form processor, plus you'll have a reliable method in your code.